# How do I create my own completion handler as part of method parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a completion handler for a certain class, instead of firing off the class's main code and waiting for a delegate callback. I've read through the Apple documentation and they don't seem to give a very good example of how to directly implement something like this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to treat the completion block just like a variable. The method will accept a block as part of it's parameters, then store it for later.

`- (void)myMethodWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(id, NSError*))handler;`

You can typedef that block type for easier reading:

`typedef void (^CompletionBlock)(id, NSError*);`

And then store your block as an instance variable:

In your @interface: `CompletionBlock _block;`

In the myMethod.. `_block = [handler copy]`

Then when you want the completion block to execute you just call it like a regular block:

`_block(myData, error);`

Comment: `copy` is required so that the block is copied to the heap (the one given to you from the client that invokes your code is stored on the stack by default).

Answer (score 34):

If it was for an asynchronous method you could do it like this

```
- (void)asynchronousTaskWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion;
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Some long running task you want on another thread

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      if (completion) {
        completion();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

this would be invoked with

```
[self asynchronousTaskWithCompletion:^{
  NSLog(@"It finished");
}];
```

Something to note is the guard to make sure that `completion` is pointing to something otherwise we will crash if we try to execute it.

Another way I often use blocks for completion handlers is when a viewController has finished and want's to be popped from a navigation stack.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onCompletion)(void);

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (IBAction)doneTapped;
{
  if (self.onCompletion) {
    self.onCompletion();
  }
}

@end
```

You would set the completion block when pushing this view onto the stack

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;
{
  MyViewController *myViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
  myViewController.onCompletion = ^{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  };
}
```

Comment: wouldnt that 2nd async dispatch call fire before the long running task completes?

Comment: How would it? If the long running code hasn't completed then you won't have reached the next `dispatch_async`

Comment: Yup that whole chunk of code will be dispatched to another queue **but** the code still executes in sequence, so the 2nd call to `dispatch_async` won't occur until after the code that occurs in the long running task

Comment: I thought that was the whole idea of GCD queues? Keep the multiple queues running concurrently.  I have a code that must use the 2nd as dispatch_sync otherwise the retuned value is nil.  Does this have to do with serial and parallel queues?

Comment: Your best bet is to create a question with your specific requirements - it's kind of hard to convey much in these comments.

Answer (score 4):

Heres an example for a method that takes a String and a completion handler as variables. The completion handler can also receive a String.

**Swift 2.2 Syntax**

Defintion:

```
func doSomething(input: String, completion: (result: String) -> Void {
    print(input)
    completion(result: "we are done!")
}
```

Calling the function:

```
doSomething("cool put string!") { (result) in
        print(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chris C's answer is correct (and was very helpful to me) with one caveat:

Placing the declaration `CompletionBlock _block;` in `@interface` is not thread safe.

Put `CompletionBlock _block = [handler copy];` in `myMethod…` instead if there is any possibility that `myMethod…` will be called from multiple threads (or dispatch queues).

Thanks @Chris C.